# Merging and Saving PDF with pdfsharp only works if the target path is empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdfsharp

I'm trying to Merge X PDFs with the same name (e.g. 186666, 186666_AB, 186666-AC, 187777, 187777_AB etc.). This works fine the first time I run my program. The second time I try to run it, some PDFs are generated and some are not. So 186666 is working, and 187777 isn't working. My AntiVirus programm then puts my .exe into quarantine with the error "Unauthorized File Encryption".

So i delete all Files by hand and the Program runs through.
I delete them within my code and the program runs into quarantine when there are files in the target path.

The Program is .NET C# from Visual Basic.

I'm not so much into programming, and I don't really know what this error means or how i could fix this.

Thanks in advance :)

The Code is C#. It's running on an Win10 PC (not Server). 
The PDFs are generated from different locations. Some are from other companies, and some are printed from an Excel tool through PDFCreator.

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Deletes every File in Target Path
        DeleteFiles();
        int AnzahlBestellungen = 0;
        //Gets all pdf files from start folder
        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pfad);
        foreach (string startDatei in allFiles)
        {
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(startDatei);
            int lenght = fileName.Length;
            //6 is the shortest name for the pdf, only if this exists
            //PDFS have to be merges
            if (lenght == 6)
            {
                AnzahlBestellungen = AnzahlBestellungen + 1;
                string searchName = fileName + "*.pdf";
                //Gets PDFs with the same first 6 letters
                string[] mergeDateien = GetFiles(pfad, searchName, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                //Merges all PDFs with the same name
                Merge(mergeDateien, fileName);
            }
        }
    }



    public static void Merge(string[] pdfs, string dateiName)
    {
        //Name of the new PDF
        string dateiNameNeu = ziel + dateiName + ".pdf";
        using (PdfDocument targetDoc = new PdfDocument())
        {
            //All Names from above mentioned same names about to be merged
            foreach (string pdf in pdfs)
            {
                using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfReader.Open(pdf, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
                    {
                        PdfPage page = pdfDoc.Pages[i];
                        targetDoc.AddPage(page);
                    }
                }
            }
            targetDoc.Save(dateiNameNeu);
        }
```

The code runs smoothly while debugging. If I run the .exe, it's getting detected by AntiVirus TrendMicro server.

Comment: where is the code to check, if pdf file already exists(same name), before merging?

Comment: I Tried checking if the PDF exists. So in this example DeleteFiles() just deletes every File in the target path.
But Checking if only the PDF im merging right now exists and deleting this one didnt work either.

Comment: Is the code filename length == 6 causing it to generate few and not others? There is no exception?

Comment: So there is always one PDF with a Lenght of 6 letters (e.g. "186666".pdf). Only if this PDF exists, the program has to generate a PDF and merges every other pdf with the same 6 letters into one pdf and saves it to a new path. So Lenght == 6 always generates 1 pdf ... at least i hope so :D

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares, TrendMicro saw the Program as a Virus. After adding the .exe to the exception List, the Program ran without problems multiple times. :)